# Marketing Cloud Lightning

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can we enable the Lightning UI within Marketing Cloud? I tried to find any settings in Admin setting but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning's a CRM/Force.com thing. In Marketing Cloud, it's a buzzword that's loosely used to refer to incremental updates to the UI that pinch some of the styling of "Lightning Design System" - the CSS used by some CRM users.

There's no button to press or checkbox to tick. Bot you'll see certain parts of Marketing Cloud that have been spruced up "Lightning Style".

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks. In most of the new released demos/feature videos the Marketing Cloud looks 100% Lightning. So we just have to be patient for new releases?

Comment: Andrew is right.. Lightning is mainly a SFDC thing and SFMC uses fuelux. There are plans on the product roadmap to move SFMC to lightning UI (Aura) but no clear timelines